# Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail not returning data this week

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-billing-api

We burn through about $2,500 / month in Azure services, meaning we have plenty of services that we are getting billed for each day.

I use the Azure Powershell command `Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail`
 to get my billing data each day.

For billing dates after 12/21/2017 the powershell command does not return any data.

If I ask for data prior to 12/22/2017 I get data, so my setup is working correctly.

Is there some end of year thing going on or what?

```
$startDate = 12/27/2017
$endDate = 12/27/2017

Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail-StartDate $startDate-EndDate $endDate|
    ConvertTo-Json>$fileName
```

does not work

```
$startDate = 12/21/2017
$endDate = 12/21/2017
```

Works. This has been working for 12 months. Now starting the 22nd it does not work.

Thank you, Terrence

===============================================================

So I am looping through an array of dates. From the uploaded picture of my directory, you can see that Azure is not returning any data after 01/19/2018.
Could someone from Azure address why no data is returned from these dates?

[image]

Comment: So today I am receiving data from 12/22 - 12/31.  It would have been nice if someone on the azure team would fess up and tell us their services are not reporting data on a timely basis.

Comment: I think for billing issues, support would be free..isn't it .You also can tweet twitter support in azure,ti got response many times

Comment: What twitter account did you tweet to?

Comment: Check out Azure Support (@AzureSupport): https://twitter.com/AzureSupport?s=09

Comment: You can both tweet and message,i also     believe billing related issues are supported freely from portal if you raise a ticket

Answer (score 0):

You are simply making and direct call for info using the built in cmdlet.

So, this does not sound like a PoSH specific issue, but sounds more to me like an environmental one. I'd suspect some change to the system where you are running this.

Try running it from another machine or restarting the machine you are running it on.
Uninstall the Azure module and reinstall it.

Then see if the above comes to some sort of resolution. Otherwise this is a helpdesk call to the MS Azure Support team to see if something is happening with you tenant.

Comment: The service is running behind by 3-4 days.  Before the holidays I could always retrieve yesterday's data.